# Matching value with ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm fairly new to java and have started on `ArrayList`s and I'm stuck on a particular issue.

What I'm trying to do in the code below is have a value passed to the method  `locateCatalogue`, which will go through the array list collection to match the value entered.

Once it finds the matched value, stop executing and show how many items there are for the said item. Otherwise if the number doesn't exist just return `null`, Here's my code:

```
Arraylist<Catalogue> items;

Public locateCatalogue (int number)
    // if int number matches value entered, find number.
    for(int i=0; i < locateCatalogue.length; i++)
        if (Catalogue.get(i) = number)
            return Catalogue;
        }
        else {
            //return no value if entered value has no matching number.
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: This `Catalogue.get(i) = number` is an assignment, not a comparison. Use `==` for comparisons.

Comment: if(items.get(i) == number)
  return items;
}

Comment: this code can never compile! please provide the correct syntax next time ...

Comment: Can you please [edit] in more details on what problem you're facing? Are you getting a compiler error, a runtime error, or is there no error but it's not working as it should? We expect all questions to have a [mcve].

Comment: Here are links from Oracle's Java tutorials for: [Classes and methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/class.html), [if-then-else](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html), 
[for-loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) and [List collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html).

Answer (score 1):

the operator `=`means to define variables. For comparison use `==`. Furthermore you messed up the if statement:

```
Arraylist<Catalogue> items;

Public int locateCatalogue (Catalogue catalogue ){
for(int i=0; i < items.size(); i++)

if(items.get(i) == catalogue )
return i;


else 
return -1;
}
```

But you can not count the items you want if you return after you found the first. Also it's not clear what you want to return

Comment: items.get(i) is of type Catalogue which is not comparable to int

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for the for-loop is as follow:

```
for(int i=0; i < items.size(); i++) {
  //some code
}
```

The syntax for the if-statement is:

```
if(items.get(i) == number) {
  //some code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Catalogue locateCatalogue( int number ) {
   for( Catalogue item : items ) {
      if( item.id == number ) {
         return item;
   }
   return null;
}
```